# Arch Linux i3 Power Management Question

Tags: arch-linux, i3, power-management, suspend

I recently got into the i3 ecosystem and am starting to configure it. I noticed that the system does not auto lock and suspend like Gnome would do after certain amount of idle time. What would be your way to configure Arch Linux with i3 running to auto lock and suspend after certain period of idling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To control power-related stuff (like suspend, laptop lid closing, etc) you need to start some power management tool, e.g. you could use `mate-power-manager` from MATE. Add it to your i3 config file and configure using `Power Management` application:

```
# ~/.config/i3/config
exec --no-startup-id mate-power-manager
```

For screen lock you could use `xautolock` and `i3lock-fancy`. Add it to i3 config:

```
# ~/.config/i3/config
exec xautolock -time 30 -locker '&& i3lock-fancy -p' -notify 30 -notifier "notify-send -u critical -t 10000 -- 'LOCKING screen in 30 seconds'"
```

Above command will lock you screen after 30 minutes of inactivity with blurred screenshot of you current screen (also showing you warning 30 seconds before that).

Comment: So going into your answer, I do have some questions, I installed the mate-power-manager, bu there is no Power Management app. Is that a separate installation?

Comment: So apparently you had to go into mate-power-preferences

Comment: @Asmodean , yes, the command itself is `mate-power-preferences`, "Power Management" is its XDG name.

Comment: Would you mind looking at this? It seemed like I can't get it to work:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/629579/xautolock-configuration-in-arch-i3

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to anlar we have a solution to the problem, the tool `mate-power-manager` can suspend the system automatically, and `xautolock`, which triggers a locking mechanism actually locks your computer. My take on this was to just use the `i3lock`, as its simple functions were more than enough for me. But if you do want the fancier appearance, do use the `i3lock-fancy`

In any case, below are references to this subject and other alternatives:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management
https://github.com/meskarune/i3lock-fancy

Thanks for reading, hope this will help others out.