# xautolock configuration in Arch i3

Tags: arch-linux, i3, suspend, systemctl, lock

After recently switching to i3 in Arch, I need something to manage power. `xautolock` seemed to be a good choice.

Unfortunately, I need it to do both `systemctl suspend` and `i3lock` at the same time, but it cannot achieve that.

Eg.

```
exec_always xautolock -time 3 -locker "i3lock && systemctl suspend"
```

That does not work at all, after i3lock is triggered, suspend won't happen.

Interesting though, the fact that this:

```
bindsym $mod+Control+s exec --no-startup-id i3lock && systemctl suspend
```

Actually works, after pressing the binding, i3locks screen and system is suspended.

Please let me know if xautolock can achieve the same thing,  and what options will I need to add in order for it to work.

Thank you for taking the time for a look!

And just as a side note,

exec_always xautolock -time 3 -locker “systemctl suspend”

Works, but it only suspends machine and not lock it.

Comment: Not sure why `i3lock` and suspend not working together, but alternatively you could execute only `systemd suspend` with `xautolock` and launch `i3lock` via systemd service, see: https://www.jvt.me/posts/2019/12/03/lock-before-suspend-systemd/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this is not the perfect answer but is a workaround

i wanted this to run:

```
exec_always xautolock -time 1 -locker "i3lock && xset dpms force off"
```

But it didn't.

After reading a liitle bit the [xautolock manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xautolock) I tried this:

```
exec_always xautolock -time 1 -locker "i3lock" -killtime 1 -killer "xset dpms force off"
```

That didn't run also... So finnaly tried this:

```
exec_always xautolock -time 1 -locker "xset dpms force off" -notify 5 -notifier "i3lock -n -c 0E1621"
```

That seems to be working.

See also if you want [using xautolock and i3lock to lock/suspend after inactivity](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=208699)

Hope that this may help you!

Comment: This does work, but I feel like it is easier to just write a script, that way customization is also more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

So here was what I did.

I have yet to configure things like the color or pictures but this worked.

```
#Power Management
set $suspend /home/user/suspend/suspend.sh
exec_always --no-startup-id xautolock -time 1 -locker "sh $suspend"
```

This points the i3lock to use a script, btw, the `sh` is needed to make this work

Then you make a script at the location specified above.

```
!#/bin/bash
i3lock
systemctl suspend
```

With this content. Customize it as you want, and you are good to go!